# How to extract facility code and card id from recieved bytes from Card Reader in Android Java?

Tags: java, android

Good day,

Could you please give your ideas how to solve the above mentioned task? I built whole app and stuck there.
Code and my comments in it: https://github.com/sakenzhuma/android-mobile-reader/blob/main/MainActivity.java

```
public void onDataReceived(final byte[] bArr, final int i) {
/* This is a place where you get bytes from reader and further
need to decode and extract facility code and card id from those bytes.
Hex Result from Reader: A523000008490002734EF8B5
Binary Result from Reader: 1111111111111111111111111010010110001100100010010010101110011100111011111111111111111111111111111000111111111111111111111111101101010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Card: Proximity 35 bit HID Corporate 1000 format card, 125Mhz
Expected outcome: Facility Code: 2121 Card ID: 460590
Some calc online: https://www.brivo.com/card-calculator/
Additional info: http://www.pagemac.com/projects/rfid/hid_data_formats
* */
runOnUiThread(() -> {
    binding.edData.setText(Common.Bytes2HexString(bArr, i));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : bArr) sb.append(Integer.toBinaryString(b));
    binding.edBitPattern.setText(sb.toString());
    File path = getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null);
    File file = new File(path, "binary.txt");
    FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    stream.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
    stream.close();
});
```

}

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: people here won't click on off-site links (i'm sure you can imagine how annoying it would be to have to swap between the two constantly just to write an answer) furthermore, this doesn't help anyone in future if you ever remove that link or change the content of it. you  1) have to include all your _relevant_ code _here_ 2) have to show what you've tried and 3) ask a _specific_ question